# VB.NET ASMX returning the response header as XML instead of JSON

Tags: asp.net, ajax, vb.net, response-headers

My ASMX call is returning `Content-Type = text/xml; charset=utf-8`

I am using ASP.NET 3.5 and `jQuery.Ajax`.
Have added these things are per numerous suggestions from Stack Overflow

I have done these things

1. Done this at web.config

   ```
   <remove verb="*" path="*.asmx"/>
   <add verb="*" path="*.asmx" validate="false"
   type="System.Web.Script.Services.ScriptHandlerFactory, System.Web.Extensions, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35"/>
   ```
2. On the function call inside ASMX, I am using these

   ```
   <WebMethod()> _
   <ScriptMethod(ResponseFormat:=ResponseFormat.Json)> _
   Public Function GetCompanies(SearchedCompany As String) As String
   ```
3. the jQuery Ajax call is like this

   ```
   var searchString = "SearchedCompany=" + $(".auto-company").val();
   $.ajax({
       type: "POST",
       url: "Services/CompaniesService.asmx/GetCompanies",
       data: searchString,
       dataType: 'json',
       success: function (msg) {
           companies = msg.hasOwnProperty("d") ? msg.d : msg;
       },
       error: function (xhr, status, error) {

       }
   });
   ```

But whatever I do, the response header is still of type xml. What part am I missing here?

Disclaimer: I know this has been asked many times around here. But was not able to find any answer. As you can see, I have already implemented all of the solutions provided.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to set the contentType as well to "application/json; charset=utf-8"

http://encosia.com/using-jquery-to-consume-aspnet-json-web-services/

> Because jQuery does set the content-type on POST requests that have
>   data, the content-type gets set to the default
>   “application/x-www-form-urlencoded” initially. Then in IE7,
>   setRequestHeader was adding “application/json; charset=utf-8″ to that
>   instead of truly setting it. So, the content-type was incorrect for
>   JSON serialization and the web service was returning XML instead of
>   JSON.

Comment: +1 for the Encosia reference. I can't count the number of times I've gone back to those articles.

Comment: @naveen Please read the linked resource carefully. As indicated by the article: `A security feature of ASP.NET web services that are JSON serialized through the ASP.NET AJAX extensions is that they must be requested in a specific way. ... The request’s content-type must be: "application/json; charset=utf-8"`

Comment: @lthibodeaux thanks for the additional info, hopefully this gets him where he needs to be.

Comment: You can read more about the security features implemented to avoid XSS attacks at [this article](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2007/04/04/json-hijacking-and-how-asp-net-ajax-1-0-mitigates-these-attacks.aspx) on Scott Guthrie's blog.

Comment: pal i am worried about the response header. @lthibodeaux: what has asp.net ajax gotta do about all these?

Comment: @naveen When allowing web services to be called from script, serialization of the response is handed off by your web service to the ASP.NET AJAX extension library. The point is, have you modified your jQuery AJAX call and tested it to see if setting the `contentType` parameter has made any impact on your response header format?

Comment: sorry for being a complete pain in the a**. loong day. sorry. +1 gent and thanks  @lthibodeaux for trying to talk me out of my mistake. it worked. i had a chat with dave ward and that helped me too. extending thanks to dave. thanks guys. off to bed. long day :)